# Resource allocation in distributed systems

Tags: architecture, computer-science, distributed, distributed-system, system-design

I have a question regarding the allocation of resources in a distributed system.
Let's say we have a system of 10K hosts and we have to split an outgoing inflight bandwidth (how many items have we sent to a downstream but have not yet completed) among them according to the following limitations:

- overall the sum of the local bandwidths has to be less than  MAX_GLOBAL_BANDWIDTH
- locally, for each host the bandwidth should be at most MAX_LOCAL_BANDWIDTH
- each host will have a number of work units that need to be sent forming a backlog. Each unit of work costs exactly 1 bandwidth unit to send out.
- the hosts with a higher backlog should receive more of the bandwidth
- each host has already sent an amount of work previously which is still inflight, LOCAL_INFLIGHT, which counts towards the MAX_LOCAL_BANDWIDTH, limiting what we can send currently from the host
- optimize the overall sending of as much units of work as possible

What algorithm should we employ to distribute this inflight bandwidth fairly across the hosts and also what type of algorithm is best (distributed calculation versus a centralized approach, considering the fact we need to perform this computation often) ?

Comment: Looking forward to receive an answer.

Comment: Looking forward to hear some other suggestions and better ways of doing this.